# Styling a page by local css

Tags: css, browser

Is there some way to style an external webpage, so that when it opens in our browser, it is styled using a local css file (perhaps even a javascript). (for Firefox/Chromium)
It is possible to edit userContent.css for firefox (and equivalent file for chromium), but this in turn effects every website that would open on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has the [`-moz-document domain(...)` rule](http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2008/10/23/per-site-custom-css-in-firefox/), while Chrome has the [*Stylish* extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe)

Comment: There's Stylish plugin for Firefox as well. I'm not aware similar plugin for javascript purposes.

Answer (score 1):

`Greasemonkey!!`

Thats what userscripts are for.